# Diagnose/Fix Poor quality HP OfficeJet Pro 8025

Tags: printing, printer, inkjet-printer, hp

A picture is perhaps the best explanation.  The picture below shows the Powerpoint and resulting print.

Can anyone help on what to do? Observations:

- Blue and yellow did not print at all
- Magenta printed but looks pink.
- Magenta looked good (no small lines).  Black looked good, but then went bad.
- Magenta AND black are large stripes. The pitch of the stripes looks the same between them but the duty cycle is different.

Things done before this print

- removed cartridges, placed damp paper towel in the "trough" under the carriage.  Moved carriage back and forth with multiple towels.
- did alignment.  It failed as the scanner couldn't read the print.

[image: Display and print of MCKY test pattern]

**After clean #1:**

I did a few things unfortunately I didn't keep careful track, but some where:

- Spoon water into the openings of the print head (The thing the cartridges snap into)
- Put wet paper towel folded 6 times under print head as I moved the head back and forth.
- dripped some tap water into the cartridges.

The following images show the results and also respond to the comments.

After clean, same position, morning:
[image: clean1_morning_diningroom]

After clean, same position, morning, stack of white paper under:
[image: c1_m_d_wp]

What the lights look like:

[image: diningroom_lights]

After clean, outside overcast, morning, with stack of paper under:
[image: morning_overcast]

**Plan**

I went through 15 or so prints before it looked like what I showed.  I'm in a bit of a quandary.  The quality still is poor so I don't know if I should invest more time and money or go with a new laser.  Its a tricky balance as I don't really print things very often.

Comment: How long had it been sitting unused before this started? This is one of the reasons I gave up on inkjets 15 years ago. Every time you want to print something you spend half an hour & waste 25 sheets of paper unblocking the jets. They're just false economy. Gave it up as a bad job & bought a laser. Never looked back. First laser I bought, the toner that came with it lasted a decade, when it ran out I bought a new printer, cheaper than new toner.

Comment: @Tetsujin - same here, 14 years ago. I had a Canon colour inkjet, very good results, but shocking ink prices. It had a drawer for printing on CD-Rs and DVD-Rs (special white ones). It didn't play nice with third party inks. I got a Brother mono laser for less than a set of Canon inks would cost. When the toner ran out after 7 years, I found an ex-display unused HP colour laser, a big office beast, at my local Staples that actually cost less than the Brother mono printer had. This does play nice with 3rd party toners. I have so far spent less on buying it and toners than the new list price.

Comment: Why is the paper so dark is it not white paper?

Comment: @Ramhound - camera trying to set a white point when faced with two areas of massive difference in brightness & lighting colour - screen is far too bright & far too blue in all possibility, compared to indoor lighting, which will be far too yellow/red. With that much difference, you'd have to be using some form of HDR or some area separation in Photoshop to try balance them up & probably still fail. Rough estimate of what you'd have to do in Photoshop to balance it up a bit… https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjExx.jpg Still not perfect.

Comment: Your comments helped!  My conclusion is that the print head has dried ink.  I've updated to show the printout in better lighting.  A note to others, the test you see in my question may be a stress test.  I printed the "Printer Status Report".  That had fading but actually looked pretty nice (The cyan is still missing).

Comment: Re your last paragraph… "I don't really print things very often" This is the key point when considering inkjet vs laser. Laser never dries up. Worst case is you have to shake the cartridges every so often to separate the toner… which I have never yet done in 15 years ;) It's supposed to stir itself & so far seems to do that just fine. Lasers aren't great for photos, but fine for such as your diagram above. If you want photos once a year or three - Snappy Snaps ;))